# Given $z = \frac{1}{2}\,\tan\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \cdot q$, how can one express $a$ in terms of $z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Probably an easy math problem I think.

I have the following expression:

> $$\text{zoom} = \frac{1}{2}\,\tan\left(\frac{\text{angle}}{2}\right) \cdot q$$
>
> How do I do the inverse? I.e. start with `zoom` and determine the value of `angle`?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The inverse function of $\tan$ is $\arctan$. The rest is just algebraic manipulations.

Comment: what does 1/2/tan(..) mean? is it 0.5 Tan(...) or 1/(2*Tna(...))?

Comment: It means `0.5 Tan(...)` sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find Zoom from Angle, you make the following operations:

- Divide by $2$.
- Apply $\tan$ function
- Divide by $2$
- Multiply by $q$.

The inverse is made by applying the inverse operations in reverse order. That is, to find Angle from Zoom you make

- Divide by $q$
- Multiply by $2$
- Apply $\arctan$
- Multiply by $2$.

A teacher of mine said that the inverse of wearing the socks and then the shoes is taking off the shoes and then the socks.

Comment: Yeah, brain fart on my part. Thanks.

Comment: $\to +1$ for the last (good) sentence.